# Push to vector only one element, without repeating

Tags: c++

I have a code where i should introduce 3 numbers and an multi-dimensional array. I should print all numbers from array that are divisors with 3 numbers from start..

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r, p, k, nr, n, m, counter=0, temp;
    vector <int> numbers;

    cout << "Enter value of r, p, k: ";
    cin >> r >> p >> k;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns: ";
    cin >> n >> m;

    int T[n][m];

    cout << "Enter values: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> T[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            for(int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                numbers.push_back(T[i][j]);
                counter++;

            }
        }
    }

    for(int f = 0; f < counter; f++) {
        if(r%numbers[f]==0 && p%numbers[f]==0 && k%numbers[f]==0) {
            cout << numbers[f] << ' ';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, my question is.. how to push in vector numbers that repeats only 1 time.. I mean if in array are 2 the same number, dont print both of them but just one of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps use a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead?

Comment: Why did you use `for(int a = 0; a < 1; a++) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

A set does not allow duplicates. For example, if you insert the number 5 more than once, there will still only be one 5 in the set.

First `#include<set>`.

Then replace `vector <int> numbers;` with `set<int> numbers;`

Then replace

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for(int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
            numbers.push_back(T[i][j]);
            counter++;

        }
    }
}
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        numbers.insert(T[i][j]);
```

Then replace

```
for(int f = 0; f < counter; f++) {
     if(r%numbers[f]==0 && p%numbers[f]==0 && k%numbers[f]==0) {
         cout << numbers[f] << ' ';
     }
}
```

with

```
for (auto i = numbers.cbegin(); i != numbers.cend(); ++i)
    if(r % *i == 0 && p % *i == 0 && k % *i == 0)
        cout << *i << ' ';
```

That should do it. You can eliminate the counter variable from the program because numbers.size() gives you the number of objects in the set. Also, your temp variable is not used, so eliminate that as well. Also, note that set is an ordered container, so printing it like this will print the numbers in ascending order.

(Also note that the length of an array such as int arr[3]; must be known at compile time to be strictly valid C++. Here 3 is a literal and so is known at compile time. Asking the user to input the length of the array means that it is not known at compile time.)

Answer (score 0):

After you fill your vector, you can first sort all elements in it and than call `std::unique`, to remove all duplicates from it.

Try to look references for [std::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) and [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)